# About Depth first search

Tags: data-structures

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsyb2.jpg)

Is 
1) A D F E G C B and; 
2) A D F E G B C is one of deep-first transverse?

The code below is written in java and method1 and method2 is two different implementation.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Stack;

/**
 * Created by raymond on 12/05/2017.
 */
class Node {
    public char ele;
    public ArrayList<Node> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();
    public boolean visited = false;

    public Node(char ele) {
        this.ele = ele;
    }
}


public class Test {
    private static HashMap<Character, Node> nodes = new HashMap<Character, Node>() {{
        put('A', new Node('A'));
        put('B', new Node('B'));
        put('C', new Node('C'));
        put('D', new Node('D'));
        put('E', new Node('E'));
        put('F', new Node('F'));
        put('G', new Node('G'));

    }};

    static void addNeighbors() {
        nodes.get('A').neighbors.add(nodes.get('B')); //A
        nodes.get('A').neighbors.add(nodes.get('D')); //A

        nodes.get('B').neighbors.add(nodes.get('A')); //B
        nodes.get('B').neighbors.add(nodes.get('C')); //B
        nodes.get('B').neighbors.add(nodes.get('E')); //B
        nodes.get('B').neighbors.add(nodes.get('G')); //B

        nodes.get('C').neighbors.add(nodes.get('B')); //C
        nodes.get('C').neighbors.add(nodes.get('D')); //C
        nodes.get('C').neighbors.add(nodes.get('F')); //C

        nodes.get('D').neighbors.add(nodes.get('A')); //D
        nodes.get('D').neighbors.add(nodes.get('C')); //D
        nodes.get('D').neighbors.add(nodes.get('F')); //D


        nodes.get('E').neighbors.add(nodes.get('B')); //E
        nodes.get('E').neighbors.add(nodes.get('F')); //E
        nodes.get('E').neighbors.add(nodes.get('G')); //E

        nodes.get('F').neighbors.add(nodes.get('C')); //F
        nodes.get('F').neighbors.add(nodes.get('D')); //F
        nodes.get('F').neighbors.add(nodes.get('E')); //F

        nodes.get('G').neighbors.add(nodes.get('B')); //G
        nodes.get('G').neighbors.add(nodes.get('E')); //G
    }

    static void method1() {
        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
        Node currentNode = nodes.get('A'); //Start node
        stack.push(currentNode);
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            currentNode = stack.pop();
            currentNode.visited = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < currentNode.neighbors.size(); i++) {
                if(currentNode.neighbors.get(i).visited) continue;
                stack.push(currentNode.neighbors.get(i));
                currentNode.neighbors.get(i).visited = true;
            }
            System.out.print(currentNode.ele + " ");
        }
    }

    static void method2() {
        Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<Node>();
        Node currentNode = nodes.get('A'); //Start node
        stack.push(currentNode);

        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            currentNode = stack.pop();
            if(currentNode.visited) continue;

            for(int i = 0; i < currentNode.neighbors.size(); i++) {
                stack.push(currentNode.neighbors.get(i));
            }


            System.out.print(currentNode.ele + " ");
            currentNode.visited = true;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        addNeighbors();
        method1();
        System.out.println();
        for(Node n :nodes.values()) n.visited = false; //reset
        method2();
    }

}
```

1) Are method1 and method2 are also Depth first search?

2) What different between these methods?

3) For the method1 it just go through to G and the back to C B. The level of depth is only 5. But for the second method, it don't need to go back to C B and only one path. The level of depth is 7. Is method1 is also a DFS?

Comment: Please get rid of the source code and replace it with ideas, pseudo code and arguments of correctness. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/64/) and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/390/) for related meta discussions.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 0):

Codebot basically the implementation of BFS(Breath First Search) and DFS(Depth First Search) are totally different. Let assume our graph in this format :-

```
     A
   /   \
  B     C
 /
D
```

So if you do BFS, your path traversal should be:-

```
 A->B->C->D
```

And for DFS, it should be:-

```
 A->B->D->C
```

Hope this clears your doubts.

Comment: why do you think that `method2()` is `BFS` ?

Comment: aah my bad I took it wrong for queue, it was stack, ya so it's DFS...

Comment: I have updated my answer, sorry for the confusion